# Scikit-learn Ridge Regression with unregularized intercept term

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Does the scikit-learn Ridge regression include the intercept coefficient in the regularization term, and if so, is there a way to run ridge regression without regularizing the intercept?

Suppose I fit a Ridge Regression:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

mymodel = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0.1, fit_intercept=True).fit(X, y)
print mymodel.coef_
print mymodel.intercept_
```

for some data X, y where X does not include a column of 1's. fit_intercept=True will automatically add an intercept column, and the corresponding coefficient is given by mymodel.intercept_. What I'm unable to figure out is whether this intercept coefficient was part of the regularization summation in the optimization objective.

According to
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html, 
the optimization objective is to minimize with respect to w:

> ||X*w - y||**2 + alpha* ||w||**2

(using the L2 norm). The second term is the regularization term, and the question is whether it includes the intercept coefficient in the case where we set fit_intercept=True; and if so, how to disable this.

Answer (score 9):

The intercept is not penalized.  Just try a simple 3 point example with a large intercept.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

x=np.array([-1,0,1]).reshape((3,1))
y=np.array([1001,1002,1003])
fit=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0.1,fit_intercept=True).fit(x,y)

print fit.intercept_
print fit.coef_
```

The intercept was set to the MLE intercept (1002), while the slope was penalized (.952 instead of 1).

Comment: This is not clear to me, e.g. according to the following example the intercept changes with different value of alpha:                                         from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = 0.1, normalize=False, fit_intercept=True)
X=np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]])
y= np.array([0, .1, 1])
clf.fit(X,y)

Comment: Sorry for taking over a year to get back to you.  The MLE solution gives the intercept which perfectly reconstructs the mean of all the points.  As in, the fit model evaluated at the mean of all the X's should equal the mean of all the y's.  That is still true for you.  middle_x = np.mean(X, axis=0); middle_y = np.mean(y); np.sum(clf.coef_ * middle_x) + clf.intercept_ == middle_y; #True

Comment: This should be marked at the right answer. intercept=mean(y) shows the intercept is unregularized.